# Geometric meaning of the formula

Tags: integration

Suppose $f(x)$, $g(x)$ to be the functions and $[a,b]$ the interval. Then

$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)dx$$

represents the area "between" $f(x)$, $g(x)$ on $a,b$. However, what is the "geometric" meaning of the squared difference

$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)^2dx$$

of $f(x)$, $g(x)$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, "represents the area..." :(1) it is **the geometric area** between the graphs of these two functions iff $\;f>g\;$ on $\;[a,b]\;$, otherwise (2) it is **the algebraic area**  of this domain, and it can be positive, negative or zero.

Comment: What makes you think there is one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One geometric meaning of $\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x))^2\,dx$ is *the square of the distance between the functions $f$ and $g$*. When I say "distance" I mean distance in the sense of a [normed vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space). That is, you can make a (huge!) space whose vectors are ($L^2$-integrable) functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$ and where you measure the *size* of a vector (i.e. function) $f$, written $\|f\|$, by
$$
\|f\|=\bigg[\int_a^b f(x)^2\,dx\bigg]^{1/2}.
$$
This size function has the properties that

- $\|f\|=0\iff f=0$ (The only function with zero size is $0$. This should be obvious.)
- $\|af\|=|a|\|f\|$ for $a\in\mathbb R$ (Size respects scaling. This should be obvious.)
- $\|f\|+\|g\|\geq\|f+g\|$ (The [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Normed_vector_space). This is probably not obvious.)

and these properties are what allow me to say that it "measures size".
Then whenever you have two functions $f$ and $g$, the "size" of $f-g$ is simply the distance between them, and
$$
\|f-g\|^2=\int_a^b(f(x)-g(x))^2\,dx,
$$
as I claimed at the beginning of this answer.

I used a lot of terms that you may not be familiar with. Did that make any sense?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, it is clear and easy to understand.